# Simple Cardinality Proof

Tags: set, isabelle, cardinality

So I'm trying to perform a simple proof using cardinalities. It looks like:

```
⟦(A::nat set) ∩ B = {}⟧ ⟹ (card (A ∪ B) = card A + card B)
```

Which seems to makes sense, but for some reason `blast` hangs, the rest of the provers fail to apply, and `sledgehammer` times out. Is there a gap in what I think I know about cardinalities? If not, how can I prove this lemma?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the lemma you are trying to prove does not appropriately consider the case of infinite sets.

In Isabelle/HOL, infinite cardinalities are represented by zero. As we can see by the following lemma.

```
lemma "¬(finite A) ⟹ card A = 0"
  by simp
```

If we consider the case of an infinite set, `A`, and a set of one element, `B`, then assume the intersection, `A ∩ B` is an empty set.

We are left with:

`card (A ∪ B) = 0` as their union will also be infinite.

`card A = 0`

`card B = 1`

So we can see that in this case, the lemma does not hold.

The lemma can be corrected by asserting both sets are finite:

```
lemma
  "⟦finite A; finite B; ((A::nat set) ∩ B) = {}⟧ ⟹ (card (A ∪ B) = card A + card B)"
  by (simp add: card_Un_disjoint)
```

Which is essentially the same as the `card_Un_disjoint` used by the proof:

```
lemma card_Un_disjoint: "finite A ⟹ finite B ⟹ A ∩ B = {} ⟹ card (A ∪ B) = card A + card B"
  using card_Un_Int [of A B] by simp
```